# wav file length is 0 seconds, but the file size is being increased anyway. NAudio,

Tags: c#, naudio

```
    string path = string.Empty;
        ConcurrentQueue<string> recQue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        private async void SaveAudioRecording()
        {
            timer.Dispose();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\AudioRecordings_" + clientSession.clientInfo[0];
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            
            using (MemoryStream audioDataStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                MixingSampleProvider mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(41100, 1));

                while (recQue.TryDequeue(out string first))
                {
                    string firstDel = first.Substring(first.IndexOf('§'), 4);

                    if (recQue.TryDequeue(out string second))
                    {
                        string secondDel = second.Substring(second.IndexOf('§'), 4);

                        first = first.Replace(firstDel, string.Empty);
                        second = second.Replace(secondDel, string.Empty);

                        if (firstDel != secondDel)
                        {
                            mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(41100, 1));

                            first = first.Replace(firstDel, string.Empty);
                            second = second.Replace(secondDel, string.Empty);

                            byte[] firstAudioData = Convert.FromBase64String(first);
                            byte[] secondAudioData = Convert.FromBase64String(second);

                            MemoryStream[] memoryStreams = { new MemoryStream(), new MemoryStream() };

                            await memoryStreams[0].WriteAsync(firstAudioData, 0, firstAudioData.Length);
                            await memoryStreams[1].WriteAsync(secondAudioData, 0, secondAudioData.Length);

                            foreach (var stream in memoryStreams)
                            {
                                await stream.FlushAsync();
                                var reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(41100, 1));
                                var waveProvider = reader.ToSampleProvider();
                                mixer.AddMixerInput(waveProvider);
                                var tempBuffer = new float[mixer.WaveFormat.SampleRate * mixer.WaveFormat.Channels * 5]; // 5-second buffer
                                int samplesRead;

                                while ((samplesRead = mixer.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                                {
                                    var byteBuffer = new byte[samplesRead * sizeof(float)];
                                    Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBuffer, 0, byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
                                    await audioDataStream.WriteAsync(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            first = first.Replace(firstDel, string.Empty);
                            second = second.Replace(secondDel, string.Empty);

                            byte[] firstAudioData = Convert.FromBase64String(first);
                            byte[] secondAudioData = Convert.FromBase64String(second);

                            await audioDataStream.WriteAsync(firstAudioData, 0, firstAudioData.Length);
                            await audioDataStream.WriteAsync(secondAudioData, 0, secondAudioData.Length);
                            await audioDataStream.FlushAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        first = first.Replace(firstDel, string.Empty);
                        byte[] firstAudioData = Convert.FromBase64String(first);
                        await audioDataStream.WriteAsync(firstAudioData, 0, firstAudioData.Length);
                        await audioDataStream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
                WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Audio_recording_" + Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Count().ToString() + ".wav"),mixer.WaveFormat);
                WriteWavHeader(writer, Convert.ToInt32(audioDataStream.Length));
                audioDataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await audioDataStream.CopyToAsync(writer);
                await writer.FlushAsync();
            }
            recQue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            recordButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }


        private void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int audioDataSize)
        {
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
            {
                writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"));
                writer.Write(audioDataSize + 36); // Total file size - 8 bytes
                writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVE"));
                writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fmt "));
                writer.Write(16); // Length of format data
                writer.Write((ushort)1); // PCM format
                writer.Write((ushort)1); // Not Stereo
                writer.Write(41100); // Sample rate
                writer.Write(82200); // Byte rate (Sample rate * Channels * BitsPerSample / 8)
                writer.Write((ushort)2); // Block align (Channels * BitsPerSample / 8)
                writer.Write((ushort)16); // Bits per sample
                writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data"));
                writer.Write(audioDataSize); // Size of audio data
            }
        }
```

The waveheader method does work,(Confirmed), The audio file which is generated will be 0 seconds long regardless of the file size.

I was trying to mix two different raw audio streams into one output if firstDEl and secondDel don't match, else it should add them first and second to a memorystream, In the end, I want to create a .wav file with the output, I was expecting that the more audio data which was added the audio duration would increase, but only the file size did.

What could possibly cause the issue?

Comment: Why would you write the WAV header yourself? Isn't the idea of WaveFileWriter  that it does just that for you? At least that would be my expectation when I use an Audio library. I want to focus on doing advanced stuff, not low level bit fiddling.

Comment: The whole code is a bit weird. Do you actually know what you are doing? Why would you create a BinaryWriter with UTF8 encoding, but whenever you write a string, you use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mre]. Remove all the UI code for enabling or disabling buttons. Use a Console application instead.

Comment: The audio data chunks is in base64 string formate in the queue. In order to use delimiters. If the delimiters idnecatse that there is audio from tweo different channel after each other in the queue they should mix.